# How can I list lambda functions and their aliases using bash

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, function, aws-lambda, alias

I want to list all Lambda functions and their aliases using bash. I could not find a direct CLI cmd to list aliases and list functions.

`aws lambda list-functions` only lists functions

`aws lambda list-aliases --function-name` only lists aliases for a given function name

I was looking for a combined solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
functions=`aws lambda list-functions --query "Functions[*].{FunctionName:FunctionName}" | awk -F\: '{print $2}' | tr -d '"'`
for function in $functions;
do
    echo "function=$function"
    aliases=`aws lambda list-aliases --function-name $function --query "Aliases[*].{AliasArn:AliasArn}" | tr -d '"' | awk -FAliasArn\: '{print $2}'`
    for alias in $aliases;
    do
    echo "alias=$alias"
    done
done
```

Comment: Or `aws lambda list-functions --query "Functions[].[FunctionName]" --output text` to populate a list of functions without having to resort to awk/tr.